# How can I group up Jenkins build artifacts in to folders?

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a large Maven project that is being built by Jenkins. The Jenkins build currently archives about 30 artifacts - zip files, rpms, jars and various other bits and pieces for the various build platforms.

These artifacts are shown very nicely on the build results page, but testing teams find it awkward to find the build artifacts for their tests.

My question is; **How can I group the artifacts up in folders?**

This would make it a little easier for testers to find the files that they are after.  Folders like "Fedora RPMs", "Documentation", "Developer JARs", etc. The artifacts come from all over the build workspace (mostly Maven $project/target/ directories).

An objective is to do this artifacts grouping/folders with no additional services (eg, pushing artifacts to a FTP server isn't great - we'd like to keep them nicely grouped up in Jenkins). A Jenkins plugin would be absolutely fine.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [Flexible Publish plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Flexible+Publish+Plugin) could help?